# How to add an overlay-section using three.js and orbit-controls which reacts to movement of main view?

Tags: javascript, three.js, overlay, visualization

I want to add a section in one corner of my main view in which I display a small version of the main view.

I am programming a webpage using JavaScript with three.js. I have a main view window in which I display some geometries. There are rotatable and movable using OrbitControls.

In the corner of my main view I want an separate section, in which I can display a small cube, which rotates the same way my main-view rotates. But I shall not zoom in or out if I zoom the main view.

```
var orientationGeometry = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
camera.add( orientationGeometry );

// in animate function:
orientationCube.rotation.x = controls.getPolarAngle();
orientationCube.rotation.y = controls.getAzimuthalAngle();
```

This rotates the small cube correctly and by adding this cube as a child to the camera it stays fixed on the screen. But when I zoom in or out this small Box as well zooms away from the camera.

Is there a way to make an extra section like shown in the attached image?

[image: wished output]

Comment: Maybe you can use the following official example as a code template. It renders a second "inset" scene similar to your screenshot: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat

Answer (score 1):

To render a second viewport on the screen you can enable `WebGLRenderer.ScissorTest,` set the desired `scissor`, scale the viewport accordingly and render the scene again. Don't forget to `clearDepth()` or nothing will get rendered.

Now, in order to get a different camera behavior, you need to add a second camera to the scene and update it depending on your needs. If you want it to rotate and move just like the full-screen camera, you need to update those parameters.

In order to keep a fixed zoom state, you can get the normalized position of the camera and multiply by the set distance you want to use.

```
function animate() {

    // render full scene.
    // ...

    // setup scissor viewport.
    renderer.clearDepth(); // important!
    renderer.setScissorTest( true );
    renderer.setScissor( 20, 20, insetWidth, insetHeight );
    renderer.setViewport( 20, 20, insetWidth, insetHeight );

    // update second camera. 
    camera2.position.copy( camera.position );
    camera2.position.normalize().multiplyScalar( distance );
    camera2.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );

    // render small scene.
    renderer.render( scene, camera2 );

    renderer.setScissorTest( false );

}
```

Here's a working example https://jsfiddle.net/qwb39spx/